# Read Rails form data inside a javascript code before doing a form submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

I have a `date_select` in my Rails form:

```
<%= date_select(:production_month, :date, order: [:month, :year], :start_year => @start_year, :end_year => @end_year) %>
```

I have a JavaScript function that gets called when the value in the above `date_select` changes:

```
$('#production_month').change(function () {alert("Yayyy!!!")});
```

Can I read the value of the `date_select` inside an `erb` code which is inturn inside the JavaScript function above?

Comment: Try this $(this).val();

Comment: Is that a Ruby syntax?

Comment: No that is JS syntax

Comment: I  able to read the value in JavaScript code. But I need to run a rails query using the values selected in my `date_select`. And I cannot use JavaScript variables inside my rails query. Is there a way to read the `date_select` values using Ruby syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use below code**

```
$('#production_nmonth').change(function() {
    var date = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'controller/action'
        data: {dateValue: date},
    success: function(result){
        $('#fieldID').val(result);
    }
    });      
}
```

**write a action in controller and write a logic you want**

```
def action 
   date = params[:dateValue]
   -- do functionality which you want--
   return data
end
```

**Use byebug for to check data flow**

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I need to be able to do this in Ruby instead of JavaScript. To be more precise, I need to be able to do this in an `erb` code inside a JavaScript function

Comment: Then you can use model , like before_save (or) you can use helper_method in controller , And you can  call helper_method in view. (or) you cab write ajax call for onchange function .

Comment: Say I make an ajax call to the controller and update an instance variable in the controller. I need a label in the form UI to reflect the changed value of this instance variable. How can I achieve this please? That's my ultimate goal. (the label will display the number of working days in a month+ year. I need to 1) pass the month and year from date_select to controller 2) and in the controller I need to run a query to fetch the number of working days in that month + year and 3) the label in the form UI needs to display this new calculated value that's available in the controller )

Comment: Oh ok , write ajax call for onchange and call controller action and wirte the functionality and return the data. In ajax write success function to receive the data from controller. and take css ID for field you want to assign new value . write like this in ajax success call  $('#fieldID").val(data) .

Comment: please check above changed code. Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: This code makes a lot of sense. I tried the same. I just get one error though - `No template found for ForecastController#update_production_month, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 193ms`. This is my routes.db entry: `post '/forecast/update_production_month', to: "forecast#update_production_month"`

Comment: And this is my javascript function:    `month = $('#production_month_date_2i').val();
                     year = $('#production_month_date_1i').val();
                     
                     $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "/forecast/update_production_month",
                      datatype: "json",
                      data: "prod_month=" + month + "&prod_year=" + year,

                      success: function(result){
                        $('#work_days_label_20').val(result);
                      }`

Comment: My controller gets called fine now and I am able to print the value from `date_select` inside my controller function. But for some reason I get the above mentioned error that I am missing some template and the value returned from my controller function does not get set in the label in the form as I expected

Comment: 1. I think Rails is looking for a `update_production_month.erb` which I don't have. Hence probably the error. Is there a way to invoke the controller and not re-render the page? 2. The return value from my controller function - is that nor getting passed over because of my render error? Or am I doing something else wrong here?

Comment: try to render data in json format , why because rails always looks for html page once you called the controller action.

Comment: I already am using json format (kindly refer my last code snippet above). Am I missing something else to accomplish using json format? (I am using `datatype: "json"` to accomplish this currently. Is there something more that needs to be done?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184788/discussion-between-user3678149-and-biju).